# Azure AD and Entity Framework Core

Tags: azure-active-directory

Azure AD

- First, due to area restrictions, we are not using Azure AD B2C. We tested this option in the end of the last year but it was not stable. Azure AD B2B looks more stable, but we still have some beta API’s, like the invitation one.
- The invitation procedure is working fine, but we could not customize the language. This would be helpful. We could customize the screen as we click in Get Started. However, when the user is already a member, we could not customize the login screen. We tried to do so, but unfortunately, it did not work, as you can see on the pictures.
- Another point that I would like to comment is the process to transit between one Web App to another (we have five web apps using the same AD authentication process). The time to transit is too slow sometimes. I do not know if there is a different way to configure it.

Entity Framework Core

- For basic use, EF Core is working fine, with a good performance.
- However, we have difficulties regarding using EF Core for a multi-tenant scenario. In our scenario, a single user (owner of a supermarket, for example) can have access to different databases (stores). The solution we worked together with Felipe and Waldemir was setting up different schemas to different customers and stores. Therefore, we have to change the schema we are using online. We could handle it using EF Core, but it was not a simple task.
- Talking about simple tasks in EF Core, we discovered that WITH NO LOCK and some Group By statements do not create a good SQL command. Our decision to this scenario is to work with some Stored Procedures. Maybe we are creating the lambda statement in a wrong way, but we need some documentation to do so.

Comment: Hi Felipe. I see that you are new to Stackoverflow. If you are asking a question, please provide details about what you have tried, preferably with code. Also, please keep it to one question per post. If you are providing feedback to Microsoft, you should probably use Uservoice or another, more direct way, to contact them.

Comment: Also you should provide more details about your question , such as which login screen you want to customize  , normal user login page ?